# Реализация интерфейса IFormattable в классе матрица

Tags: c#, ооп

Как реализовать этот интерфейс в классе матрица? Например, я хочу выводить на консоль элементы матрицы в таком виде:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0,20:F3}", m1);
```

С указанной шириной выводит только 1 строчку, далее сбрасывается.
Так реализован метод ToString:

```
public override string ToString() {
    var str = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            str.Append($"{arr[i, j]}  ");
        }
        str.AppendLine();
    }

    return str.ToString();
}
```

Comment: В IFormattable метод с другой сигнатурой так то: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.iformattable

Comment: Я понимаю, просто ToString для примера показал.

Comment: не надо добавлять код для примера, добавляйте тот код, с которым у вас проблемы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если взять за основу ваш код с минимальными исправлениями:

```
public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider = null)
{
    var str = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            str.AppendFormat(formatProvider, format, arr[i, j]);
        }
        str.AppendLine();
    }

    return str.ToString();
}
```

Использование:

```
Console.WriteLine(matrix.ToString("{0,20:F3}"));
```

---

Вы хотите следующее использование:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0,20:F3}", matrix);
```

При таком вызове в метод `ToString` в качестве параметра `format` передаётся строка `F3`. А значение длины `20` использует сам метод `WriteLine` при выводе *всей* итоговой строки. Поэтому не представляется возможным именно такое использование.

Придётся разработать собственный формат. Например, длину одного значения матрицы будем указывать после знака `_` (можете поменять на любой другой на свой вкус).

```
public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider = null)
{
    var splitted = format.Split('_');
    var numberFormat = splitted[0];
    int width = int.Parse(splitted[1]);

    var resultFormat = $"{{0,{width}:{numberFormat}}}";

    var str = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            str.AppendFormat(formatProvider, resultFormat, arr[i, j]);
        }
        str.AppendLine();
    }

    return str.ToString();
}
```

Использование:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:F3_20}", matrix);
```

Здесь
`0` - номер параметра, используемый методом `WriteLine`.
`F3` - один из стандартных форматов чисел.
`_` - разделитель.
`20` - ширина выравнивания.

Если вызывать метод `ToString` непосредственно, то теперь передаём в него только наш формат:

```
Console.WriteLine(matrix.ToString("F3_20"));
```

Конечно, код сырой. Он нуждается, по крайней мере, в проверке входных параметров.

Comment: Спасибо, а возможно использование без явного вызова ToString? Как в моём примере?

Comment: @ДмитрийКузьменко - дополнил