# Не могу задать разделитель для разрядов числа

Tags: c#

Хочу, чтобы у чисел каждый разряд был через пробел. То-есть, чтобы `1234` превращалось в `1 234`.

Я написал такой код:

```
var format = (NumberFormatInfo)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.Clone();
format.NumberGroupSeparator = " ";

Console.Write(1234d.ToString(format));
```

Почему это не работает??

Comment: `$"{1234d:N0}"`. Если у вас WPF (судя по пред. вопросу), то `{Binding SomeValue, StringFormat=N0}`, то есть за формат отвечает XAML, не пишите этих конверторов в коде.

Comment: [Документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) - для слабаков? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Свойство [NumberGroupSeparator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupseparator?view=net-5.0) используется со строкой стандартного формата "N" для определения символа, разделяющего группы целой и дробной части.

```
1234d.ToString("N", format)
```

Результат:

```
1 234.00
```

Дополнительно можно задать

```
format.NumberDecimalDigits = 0;
```

Результат

```
1 234
```

---

Примечание: смотрите документацию на английском языке. В русском переводе имеются ошибки.

Comment: а можно что бы запятая была только если есть символы после неё, а не нули

Comment: @KuzCode - отредактируйте вопрос, добавив в него новое требование

Comment: @KuzCode - думаю, это не сделать одной лишь строкой форматирования. Придётся предварительно проверять, является ли число целым (`if`) и в зависимости от этого применять разное форматирование.

Comment: @KuzCode - как вариант, можно сделать собственный формат. [Пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/977690/184217)

Answer (score 0):

```
1234.ToString("# ##0")
```

Хотя, раз уж в вопросе InvariantCulture, то:

```
1234.ToString("# ##0", format)
```

Comment: ну это уже точно свежак. ай-яй-яй. опять никаких пояснений, что это за загадочные решётки с пробелами. и почему первая решётка отделена пробелом от остальных, и почему их всего три, и зачем там ещё ноль в конце. // можно ведь хоть вкратце-то расшифровать?

Comment: Это больше похоже на комментарий, чем на ответ.

Comment: @aepot, раз работает, значит ответ)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, 22 символа кода объяснять, из которых 4 - число, а ещё 11 - вызов метода? ((( Тут просто формат, которые делает то, что спросил автор.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, исправил.